# How to split the string from an array of strings in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, split

I have an `array` like :

```
dateTime = ["2018/06/25 05:32:30","2018/05/25 02:37","2018/04/25 05:32:50","2018/07/25 06:30:30"]
```

Need to split the strings and get the response as :

```
time = ["05:32:30","02:37","05:32:50","06:30:30"]
```

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: could you please tell me why you changed my answer as not accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `flatMap`:

```
let dates = ["2018/06/25 05:32:30","2018/05/25 02:37","2018/04/25 05:32:50","2018/07/25 06:30:30"]
let times = dates.flatMap({ $0.split(separator: " ").last ?? nil })
print(times)
// prints: ["05:32:30", "02:37", "05:32:50", "06:30:30"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this below solution to get the times from all elements.

```
let dateTime = ["2018/06/25 05:32:30","2018/05/25 02:37","2018/04/25 05:32:50","2018/07/25 06:30:30"]  
let array = dateTime.map { $0.components(separatedBy: " ")[1] }
 //["05:32:30", "02:37", "05:32:50", "06:30:30"]
```

Comment: Just want to note, that using subscript `[1]` may cause a null pointer if the second element is not found. That's why `flatMap` is better. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Loops each items & use split function

```
let times = dateTime.compactMap { $0.split(separator: " ").last }
```